# How to update or insert a record in a postgres table which is obtained by doing another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, aggregate

I want to write a simple statistic tool that is doing some queries and saving the results in a nother table from the same database.

Mainly I want to tracke the number of items in different tables, number of touched items during a month and so on. This would allow me to get some analytics regarding the usages of the system, information that I will not be able to get just by looking at the database status at one moment.

Let's say that I have this query:

```
select count(*) as mytab_mcount from mytab where updated > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';
```

Now I do want to store the result of this query in a `stats` table so I can query it in order to get some trend data.

Clearly I could code this in something but I am wondering if I can do this only in SQL, Postgres blend of it.

I want to put the result in a table like

```
date         mytab_mcount    some_stat
2013-09-01   1234            NUL
```

Clearly the SQL should insert a new row or update the existing one.

Is this possilbe, can you put a basic example?

I this could be done in a single query it would be very easy to automate this, keeping all the logic in one place, and having a cron job to execute it.

Comment: It sounds like you want `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` as an `UPSERT` or `MERGE`. You're not likely to find a clean, concurrency-safe, simple way to do this in Pg.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You may be over-thinking this. Doesn't sound like multi-user concurrency or even uniqueness are the problem. More like a basic case of UPDATE / INSERT with another table as source.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO stat_table (stat_date, table_name, row_count, some_stat)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 'mytab', count(*), 2+3
FROM mytab 
WHERE updated > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';
```

Or

```
UPDATE stat_table 
SET row_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM mytab WHERE updated > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'),
    stat_date = CURRENT_DATE,
    some_stat = (SELECT 1+3)
WHERE table_name = 'mytab';
```

Comment: sounds good for a start, I may be able to squeeze these into a single query. I will back to update your answer with the verified solution ;) Thanks.